# Select the most recent row from a log table using timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a table for logging a Facebook application user actions. I want to get the latest row that is not older then 9 minutes for a specific action ID. The table has a lot of columns of other statistical information, so I will show only 2 of the rows that represent the problem:

```
timestamp                  facebookID   producerID      eventID   actionID   numOfTickets
2012-05-28 13:16:38     100003286974944    9             1741        cpf      2
2012-05-28 13:16:13     100003286974944    9             1741        cpf      4
```

What I want to do is getting the latest row where `actionID = 'cpf'`.

What I've tried is:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', y.firstName, y.lastName) as fullName, x.facebookID, x.numOfTickets, MAX(x.timestamp) 
FROM E4S_ANALYTICS.e4s_analytic_data x INNER JOIN E4S_FB.e4s_user_details y ON x.facebookID = y.facebookID 
WHERE (x.actionID = 'CPF' AND x.numOfTickets > 0 AND x.producerID = 9 AND TIMEDIFF(NOW() , x.timestamp) < '00:09:00' 
AND x.facebookID IN (SELECT facebookID FROM  E4S_FB.e4s_session_data WHERE 
                     TIMEDIFF(NOW() , sessionStart) < '00:09:00' ))
```

The result of the query is:

```
facebookID      numOfTickets    MAX(x.timestamp)
100003286974944  4              2012-05-28 13:16:38
```

The timestamp returned is correct but the `numOfTickets` is 4 instead of 2.

For note, the inner query:

```
SELECT facebookID FROM  E4S_FB.e4s_session_data 
WHERE TIMEDIFF(NOW() , sessionStart) < '00:09:00' ))
```

Is used to see who is still logged in to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', y.firstName, y.lastName) AS fullName,
       x.facebookID,
       x.numOfTickets,
       x.timestamp
FROM   (
         SELECT *
         FROM   E4S_ANALYTICS.e4s_analytic_data
         WHERE  actionID = 'cpf'
            AND numOfTickets > 0
            AND producerID = 9
            AND TIMEDIFF(NOW() , timestamp) < '00:09:00' 
            AND (facebookID, timestamp) IN (
                  SELECT   facebookID, MAX(timestamp)
                  FROM     E4S_ANALYTICS.e4s_analytic_data
                  WHERE    actionID = 'cpf'
                       AND numOfTickets > 0
                       AND producerID = 9
                       AND TIMEDIFF(NOW() , timestamp) < '00:09:00' 
                       AND facebookID IN (
                             SELECT facebookID
                             FROM   E4S_FB.e4s_session_data
                             WHERE  TIMEDIFF(NOW() , sessionStart) < '00:09:00'
                           )
                  GROUP BY facebookID
                )
       ) AS x
  INNER JOIN E4S_FB.e4s_user_details AS y USING (facebookID)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot !! It is working great, I've tried this with a few facebook IDs and the result are as expected. Will you have time to explain this query ? as it seems I can learn a lot from It. Didn't think it will be so complicated. If its too long and not comfortable  for a comment you can email me to adleralon[at]yahoo.com. And again... MANY MANY thanks !

Comment: @Alon_A: Start from the innermost subquery and work your way outwards: select all logged-in IDs, then get their maximum (most recent) timestamp of analytic data where the other desirable criteria are met, then get all analytic data where not only those desirable criteria are met but also where the timestamp is the most recent one, then join with the user details to return the columns ultimately of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using MAX()?
Assuming you've checked JOIN and SUBQUERY results.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', y.firstName, y.lastName) as fullName, x.facebookID, x.numOfTickets, MAX(x.timestamp) 
FROM E4S_ANALYTICS.e4s_analytic_data x 
INNER JOIN E4S_FB.e4s_user_details y ON x.facebookID = y.facebookID 
GROUP BY x.facebookID
WHERE (x.actionID = 'CPF' AND x.numOfTickets > 0 AND x.producerID = 9 AND TIMEDIFF(NOW() , x.timestamp) < '00:09:00' 
AND x.facebookID IN 
     (SELECT facebookID FROM  E4S_FB.e4s_session_data 
      WHERE TIMEDIFF(NOW() , sessionStart) < '00:09:00' ))
ORDER BY x.timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: Im using MAX(x.timestamp) and I cant use LIMIT 1 because in case there are many facebook ids that answers the conditions I need to return them all.

Comment: Ok, then what's the output if you run the query above (without LIMIT)?

Comment: the row with the correct date (2012-05-28 13:16:38) **but** with 4 `numOfTickets` instead of 2 `numOfTickets`

Comment: You mean the query I provided ?

Comment: Your query without the limit gives me both of the rows.

Comment: Ah, Now understood what you're looking for. updated the query (added Group by fb id).

Comment: It still returns 4 `numOfTickes` instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `order by timestamp desc` to order the column according to latest first and then select the first row.
or try using `max`.

Comment: Im using MAX(x.timestamp) and I cant selecgt only the first row because in case there are many facebook ids that answers the conditions I need to return them all.